# How to calculate the length of a data stream (.Net Stream) while consuming it

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, streaming

Basically the question is: Is there an easy way to get the length of a `Stream` that is consumed?

In a .Net service we receive a `Stream` via a .Net REST API. We save this to either a file or a database. Since we might receive a number of large messages (streams) this way we of course use streaming so we never have the full content in memory at any single time (well, at least not intentionally).

We would like to calculate the full length of the `Stream` while consuming it, but don't know if there is an easy way to do this. Clearly we cannot use the [`Length`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.length?view=netcore-3.1) property since the underlying `Stream` does not support seeking.

A way to do this would be to implement a wrapper `Stream` that keeps track of the number of bytes consumed, but that would be somewhat cumbersome. But perhaps such a solution already exists (and I'm bad at searching).

Comment: Do you also control the sending API?

Comment: @Fildor Not quite, I mean I know all of the client creators, so I can ask them nicely, but thats not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2):

If the `Stream` itself doesn't support the length, then that leaves four options:

- convey the length separately, for example the `Content-Length` header in http
- convey the length in the payload (stream contents) as a prefix (changes the data shape)
- buffer it (not recommended for large data) and look at the length once known
- track the length manually while consuming it

  - you *can* do that by decorating (wrapping) the `Stream` with *another* stream that counts the bytes consumed (exposed as `Position`), and proxy all the other APIs to the underlying `Stream`

Comment: I would like to avoid changing the service - either by requirering the `Content-Length` tag and I would also like to avoid it as part of the payload. As already implied in my question I don't want to buffer it. That leaves the suggestion I already proposed myself :-) (although I'd probably implement it differently).

Comment: @Ykok so that leaves option 4 :)

Comment: Yeah, if I can't avoid it I might just do that, and then make a NuGet package of it for others to use.